# How to use getsource with listeners

Tags: java

I am making a tool which writes the data I give to a file. Where I need help is I have four `JTextFields` in which I want to apply the same mechanism to each one. That mechanism will be written independently from the frame code, and would be about checking the data input into the field and other stuff.

I wrote that mechanism to each field and it worked, and now I am thinking about shortening the code by isolating that mechanism. I know that I must use action listeners and document listeners, but I can't figure out how to make it work with `<code>e.getsource()</code>` method.

Here is the mechanism that I need to isolate:

```
txtNa_1 = new JTextField();
//the mechanism will be about setting the field text in the beginning
//to "N/A", when focused sets to "", and when 
//focus is lost it preserve the index.


txtNa_1.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() { 

  public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {

     if (txtNa_1.getText().equals("N/A")){      
         txtNa_1.setText("");
            }}
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            if (txtNa_1.getText().equals("")){
                txtNa_1.setText("N/A");
        }}});

    txtNa_1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        txtNa_23 = txtNa_2.getText();   
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String txtNa_23 = txtNa_2.getText();    
        }

        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txtNa_23 = txtNa_2.getText();
        }});
```

Simply put, can somebody explain how to cast a `<code>getsource</code>` along with what I am trying to make? Help appreciated.

Comment: Formatting your code a bit better would look cleaner. Also, you may want to be more specific with your question.

Comment: Decompose the problem into smaller pieces.  Leave Swing out of it at first.  Write a class to do the validation; test it and put it aside.  Write a class to create the file; test it and put it aside.  Create a text only UI and use it to drive the validator and file creation.  Only then should you write the Swing UI.  One bit at a time.

Comment: `JTextField src=(JTextField)arg0.getSource();` does the trick for you

Comment: Assuming you don't have a reference to the original fields in you listened class, then you might be better to use the actionCommand property of both the field and ActionEvent